# Go Executable waits on goroutine to complete before returning result

Tags: bash, go, goroutine

Can someone explain to me why the first go executable returns the http request immediately, and the second does not.

The first, pretty obviously, listens for a post from a Github web hook.  If the hook received is a repo and a branch that we are listening for, it executes a bash script that gets the new code and rebuilds the docker containers.  This script takes about 5 minutes to execute, and it's executed perfectly every time I've run it, but the go process waits until the bash script has finished before it returns the response to the server so Github thinks that the request timed out.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "os/exec"
)

type Repository struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

//Webhook Object
type Webhook struct {
    Ref     string `json:"ref"`
    Repo    Repository `json:"repository"`
}

func valid(str string) bool {
    var arr[7] string
    arr[0] = "Repo1"
    arr[1] = "Repo2"
    arr[2] = "Repo3"
    arr[3] = "Repo4"
    arr[4] = "Repo5"
    for _, a := range arr {
        if a == str {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func rebuild() {
    exec.Command("rebuild")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var webhook Webhook
        if r.Body == nil {
                http.Error(w, "Please send a request body", 400)
            return
        }

        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&webhook)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
            return
        }
        if strings.Index(webhook.Ref, "master") != -1 {
            if valid(webhook.Repo.Name) {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", "success");
                go rebuild()
            }
        }
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8088", nil))
}
```

This second go executable runs a bash script as well. This bash script doesn't do exactly the same thing as the first, but it does run the most time consuming part of the first which is an AOT compile of an Angular application.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os/exec"
)

type Repository struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

//Webhook Object
type Webhook struct {
    Ref  string     `json:"ref"`
    Repo Repository `json:"repository"`
}

func rebuild() {
    var buff bytes.Buffer
    out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "/Users/myuser/test.sh").Output()
    if err != nil {
        buff.WriteString("Something went wrong: ")
        fmt.Println(buff.String())
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    buff.Write(out)
    fmt.Println(buff.String())
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var webhook Webhook
        if r.Body == nil {
            http.Error(w, "Please send a request body", 400)
            return
        }

        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&webhook)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
            return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", "Success")
        go rebuild()
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8088", nil))
}
```

The first when run on an EC2 instance, returns in 275 seconds.  The second when run locally, returns in ~20ms.  I can't for the life of me figure out why the first waits on the goroutine to complete before returning, but the second does not.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Logs print the Following:

```
Request Recieved At: 2017-12-15T15:17:30Z
Response sent At: 2017-12-15T15:17:30Z
Rebuild Started At: 2017-12-15T15:17:30Z
Rebuild Completed At: 2017-12-15T15:22:04Z
```

Comment: There's nothing waiting on your goroutine. You have something else going on.

Comment: @JimB Any more insight you could offer?  Something else is not particularly helpful, and it strikes me as odd that the webservice would wait the exact amount of time that the rebuild takes before it responds if it's not the rebuild that is somehow blocking the http response.  Old habits on checking the request body.

Comment: probably not related, but the docs state `For server requests the Request Body is always non-nil`, your check doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: You have no logging here at all. Add some to record what the requests were, and when everything happens.

Comment: These are shortened versions of the actual script that runs.  The real script Fwrites a timestamped record for most everything that happens.  I'll shorten the log output, run the request again, and post that.

Comment: @JimB Looks like this may be related to supervisord.  When I ran it as a systemd service, everything worked as designed.  Still no Idea the exact nature of the problem.